# Problem with Aggregate CSS files option and tmp directory

Tags: files

This issue has been asked at lots of places and posts, but none of the solutions I found helped me.

I moved a dev site to a server where it is going to go live. Right away I was puzzled why I had to manually create a `tmp` directory at the site root to get it working at all.

On the dev site, I had been running with the `Temporary directory` set to `/tmp` (note the leading slash), but on the new hosting the site forces me to remove the slash, complaining about SAFE_MODE.

The main problem though is that - even though the `tmp` directory is there and is writeable - turning on the `Aggregate and compress CSS files.` option causes the site to go into plain, no-stylesheet mode. The `Aggregate JavaScript files.` companion works just fine on the other hand.

I made sure the encoding of the CSS files is UTF-8 without BOM, as one of the posts suggested. Still - no go. Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: Do image styles work?  What does the status report say?

Comment: Good point. No, they don't, I renamed `styles` directory to force recreating the images, but it resulted in broken image references and messages like `SAFE MODE Restriction in effect.` I dbl-checked - all the dirs along the `/sites/default/files/` path are writable (777).

Comment: I think safe-mode is the root cause of your problem.  I have never seen it officially state, but safe mode causes all sorts of grief with complex PHP frameworks/applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Drupal PHP requirements](http://drupal.org/requirements/php), safe mode should be off.

It will interfere with file uploads and possibly email sending as well.

You'll probably find you need, in all the .htaccess places with:

`Options +FollowSymLinks`

to change to

`Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch`

In any case, if you can't disable PHP "safe mode" which, according to php.net is deprecated

> Safe Mode
>   This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP
>   5.4.0.

and the other options don't work - you may need to consider using another webhost.

Comment: Thanks. I will talk to them tomorrow. At any rate, the PHP version is 5.3.3 there, so I'm surprised it's ON. :)